# Going down in a i-search (ctrl-r)

Tags: bash

with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> I can `(reverse-i-search)`, and pressing again allow me to browse up in my bash history.

Is there any posibilty to going down after several <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>? other than <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> and restart from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> is the opposite direction of
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

See [Commands For Manipulating The History](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-History)
in the manual:

> reverse-search-history (C-r)
>
> > Search backward starting at the current line and moving ‘up’ through the history as necessary. This is an incremental search.
>
> forward-search-history (C-s)
>
> > Search forward starting at the current line and moving ‘down’ through the history as necessary. This is an incremental search.

Comment: thanks,but I needed to add `stty -ixon` in my **.bashrc** to make it work.